# How to pass args from sagaMiddleware to action watcher

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new to Sagas, Use to come from a redux-thunk background,
So I'm not sure what is the best way to pass arguments to my final action.
I will appreciate some kind of "For dummy answer"

The thing is, I have some object called **session** in my store.js
I create this session in the sagaMiddleware, but in order to make my functions in the sagas work, I always need to interact with this object.

So, the question is.
Using my current code, how is possible to pass some **args** (In this case "session" to the final action in sagas.js)

**store.js**  here it is "session"

```
sagaMiddleware.run(function* () {
    yield* saga1(session);
    yield* saga2(session);
  });
```

**saga1.js**

Expor actions:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    fork(watchAction1),
    fork(watchAction2),
  ];
}
```

Actions watcher

```
function* watchMyAction() {
  yield takeEvery(actionTypes.SEND_EVENT, myAction);
}
```

Action

```
function* myAction(action) { // Here I want again the sesssion
  // Action.payload stuff, here I want my session arg from loadStore.js
}
```

Comment: FYI, the session object is from a package, so I just can't reffer using some option like `refer` using the state. I suppose to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you want and picking one depends on both your use case and preference.

**The pass it down method**

The simplest way is just to pass down the object all the way down to `myAction` saga.

```
yield* saga1(session)
...
fork(watchAction1, session)
...
yield takeEvery(actionTypes.SEND_EVENT, myAction, session)
...
function* myAction(session, action) {
    console.log(session);
}
```

This is good enough solution if you have only few sagas or if the structure of your sagas is flat so you don't have to pass it down too deep.

**The import method**

Another way to go about this is to import the session object. If you need to do some initialization first, you can create a file that exports a singleton object, like so:

```
// session.js
import Session from 'session-library';

const config = {foo: 'bar'};
export default new Session(config);
```

Now you can import this file wherever you need to access your session. You don't need to pass it through multiple files/sagas just to get it to one of your sagas deep down. However, it can be a bit more problematic if you need to replace the session object.

```
// action.js
import session from 'path/to/session';

function* myAction(action) {
    console.log(session);
}
```

**The context method**

The third method is to use the `setContext/getContext` effects. This one is my personal favorite as it doesn't rely on the module system, doesn't require any special files and you can request access to the objects like `session` at the exact moment you need it - even midway saga execution.

```
// store.js
const stuffYouWantToAccess = {session};
sagaMiddleware.run(function* (stuffYouWantToAccess) {
    yield setContext(stuffYouWantToAccess);
   ...
}, stuffYouWantToAccess);

// action.js

function* myAction(action) {
    const session = yield getContext('session');
    console.log(session);
}
```

It also isn't perfect though as context works a bit like global variables and you need to access the context values using string names (`'session'`) which can be sometimes a problem (e.g. when using closure compiler or typechecking).

So pick your poison :)

Comment: Thank you, this really asnwer my question!