# redux-saga: eventChannel and listener which react callback return

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

In react-native [backhandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler) listener react to callback function and act appropriately.

I need to read my store and depending on it, return true or false.
But I cant use select effect in normal function and I cant affect listener callback function from "watchBackButton" function.

```
export function* backButtonListen() {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    const backHandlerListener = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      () => {
        emitter("back pressed");
      }
    );
    return () => {
      backHandlerListener.remove();
    };
  });
}

export function* watchBackButton() {
  const chan = yield call(backButtonListen);
  try {
    while (true) {
      let back = yield take(chan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since event channels are not bidirectional, I don't think there is a way to get some current state from saga to event channel using the `select` effect.

However, it is possible to access the store directly. There are multiple ways to get the store instance to the event channel. See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452686/how-to-pass-args-from-sagamiddleware-to-action-watcher/52456646#52456646).

Using e.g. the context method you could do something like this:

```
// redux.js
...
const store = createStore(...);
sagaMiddleware.runSaga(rootSaga, {store});

// root-saga.js
export default function * rootSaga(context) {
  yield setContext(context);
  yield fork(watchBackButton);
}

// watch-back-button.js
export function* backButtonListen() {
  const store = yield getContext('store');
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    const backHandlerListener = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      () => {
        emitter("back pressed");
        return store.getState().foo === 'bar';
      }
    );
    return () => {
      backHandlerListener.remove();
    };
  });
}

export function* watchBackButton() {
  const chan = yield call(backButtonListen);
  try {
    while (true) {
      let back = yield take(chan);
    }
}
```