# redux props not updated inner addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm using this package https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo. My problem is that when I my connectivity change it reach my function but the props are always the same, never got updated (in my state I got different values). Debugging I check that it not pass to again to mapStateToProps so maybe I'm missing something not have much experience with react.

Component

```
class AuthLoading extends Component {

handleAppStateChange = () => {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(this.handleConnectivityChange);
  };

handleConnectivityChange(connectionInfo) {
    // I reach here when my connectivity change but my props are the same(init one) when in my state I got different data.
    if (this.props.modalState === false) {
      this.props.networkActions.setNetworkConnection(connectionInfo);
      /* the network has changed */
      this.props.householdActions.getSSID();
      this.props.householdActions.getBSSID();
      this.props.toastActions.showToast(`Connection type: ${connectionInfo.type}`);
    }
    // Service Unavailable

    if (
      // this.props.loggedIn &&
      (connectionInfo.type === 'none' || connectionInfo.type === 'unknown') &&
      this.props.modalState === false
    ) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ServiceUnavailable');
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleAppStateChange();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

}
```

Container

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    loggedIn: SessionSelector.loggedIn(state.session),
    session: state.session,
    networkConnection: NetworkChangeSelector.getNetworkConnection(state.networkChange),
    profileFetchedSuccessfully: ProfileSelector.profileFetchedSuccessfully(state.profile),
    profileStatus: ProfileSelector.profileStatus(state.profile),
    modalState: ModalResolutionSelector.modalState(state.modal)
  };
};

const AuthLoadingContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(AuthLoading);

export default AuthLoadingContainer;
```

Comment: You can't mutate props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I follow this way [redux-saga: eventChannel and listener which react callback return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920597/redux-saga-eventchannel-and-listener-which-react-callback-return)

```
// redux.js
...
const store = createStore(...);
sagaMiddleware.runSaga(rootSaga, {store});

// root-saga.js
export default function * rootSaga(context) {
  yield setContext(context);
  yield fork(watchNetInfo);
}

// watch-netinfo.js
import { call, take, getContext, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import * as NavigationService from '../navigators/NavigationService';
export function* netInfoListen() {
  const store = yield getContext('store');
  return eventChannel((emitter) => {
    const netInfoListener = NetInfo.addEventListener((connectionInfo) => {
      const state = store.getState();
      emitter({
        connectionInfo,
        showUnavailable:
          (connectionInfo.type === 'none' || connectionInfo.type === 'unknown') &&
          state.modal.modalResolutionIsOpen === false &&
          Boolean(state.session.token)
      });
    });
    return () => {
      netInfoListener.remove();
    };
  });
}

export function* watchNetInfo() {
  const chan = yield call(netInfoListen);
  try {
    while (true) {
      let response = yield take(chan);
      yield put({
        type: 'NETWORK_STATUS_CONNECTION_REQUESTED',
        connection: response.connectionInfo
      });
      if (response.showUnavailable) {
        NavigationService.navigate('ServiceUnavailable');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('function*watchNetInfo -> e', e);
  }
}
```