# How to redirect user to another page on redux saga without reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

Hi I am working on a project ,in this project I am using `Redux saga` for asynchronous action.I have a question when I dispatch an action to edit the user details, if the user Details successfully gets updated ,I want to redirect user to another page. This is working in my project but it's reloading the page ,I want it should not reload the page as I am using `window.location` to redirect ,how can I use here `react-router` to stop reloading,or is there any other way to do this

```
function* fetchData(){
  try{
    
      yield call(editgetUser)
    yield put(userEditSuccess);
Window.location="/user/home"   
  } catch(e){
    yield yield put(userEditFailure);
Window.location="/user/login"   
  }
}

function* watchFetchData(){
  yield takeEvery(EDIT, fetchData);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been stucked in this kind of problem before, since you want to avoid page reload it means we have to use the history object provided by react-router-dom. We need the history object to achieve your goal but the history object is not available on the saga where the decision to navigate or not is taken, we have to find a way to pass the history object to the saga so that we can navigate from the saga. lets look at how we will achieve that

**Solution 1 (Using react hook component)**

Let say you are using react hook component thus the solution ..

```
 // component to dispatch action
 import {useHistory,useDispatch} from 'react-router-dom'
 function MainComponent(){
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return(
         <div>
             <button 
                onPress={()=>
                   dispatch({
                       type:"EDIT",
                       payload:{},
                       history:history // here we pass reference of history object
                  })}>Click ME </button>
         </div>
      )
}




// Your saga function modified
// add action as a param to fetchdata
function* fetchData(action){ // we take the action param
  try{
       yield call(editgetUser)
       yield put(userEditSuccess);
       Window.location="/user/home"  // remove this line
       action.history.push('/user/home') // add this line to your code
   } catch(e){
      yield yield put(userEditFailure);
      Window.location="/user/login"  // remove this line
      action.history.push('/user/login') // add this line to your code
   }
 }

 function* watchFetchData(){
    yield takeEvery(EDIT, fetchData);// fetch data will have an action attatched to it as a param when called
 }
```

if you are using a class component you can get history by calling this.props.history and pass the reference to the dispatched action.

Answer (score 0):

```
function* fetchData(){
  try{
    
      yield call(editgetUser)
    yield put(userEditSuccess);
    window.history.pushState({},'',"/user/home")
  } catch(e){
    yield yield put(userEditFailure);
    window.history.pushState({},'',"/user/login")  
  }
}

function* watchFetchData(){
  yield takeEvery(EDIT, fetchData);
}
```

this doc is also helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Solomon's answer, one disadvantage of sending services/non-serializable objects such as history in actions is that it bloats the action interface with implementation logic that is not relevant to the action itself from higher level perspective.

Sometimes, when the given object is relative to specific part of react tree that is unavoidable, however for global services like history you can pass these things to sagas when running the saga middleware.

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#middlewarerunsaga-args

```js
middleware.run(saga, ...args)
```

This way you can pass arguments to the root saga. When it comes to getting it to other parts of the saga tree there are multiple approaches. I'd suggest using the `setContext`/`getConext` effects. For more in depth info on this see my other answer here:
[How to pass args from sagaMiddleware to action watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452686/how-to-pass-args-from-sagamiddleware-to-action-watcher/52456646#52456646)